# Set a cell colour based on given/referenced R, G, B values

Tags: excel, vba, colors, formatting

I want to put a function into a cell, =Colour(R, G, B), where R, G, & B are selected reference cells (e.g. =Colour(A1, A2, A3) ) representing Red/Green/Blue values.  Upon filling out this function in a cell, I want it to colour the cell the corresponding RGB colour.

Having looked through many threads here, Conditional Formatting will not do this, and it seems there are problems with UDFs being able to edit cell properties without there being *dodgy* work-arounds.

Running Excel on a 64-bit, Windows 10 set up if necessary.

I'm doing colour analysis work for a materials science job.  Would be nice to have a cell, or cells, adopt the RGB colour which I can get from the CIELab colour analysis of my samples.

Comment: `RGB(100,100,100)`

Comment: [Excel Used-Defined-Functions](http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsj.htm) : "Excel will not allow a UDF written in VBA to alter anything except the value of the "cell in which it is entered.

Comment: Consider of adding some images of what are you attemping to do, is always very helpful

Comment: Those dodgy workarounds a are the only way outside using subroutines.

Comment: @ScottCraner Could you point me in the direction of how to use subroutine(s) to do this please?

Comment: Here's another link that might help you: [Set cell background color to its containing rgb values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58147570/set-cell-background-color-to-its-containing-rgb-values-how/58147715#58147715)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
Public Function PPrintRGBColor(RedComp As Integer, GreenComp As Integer, BlueComp As Integer) As String
ActiveCell.Interior.Color = RGB(RedComp, GreenComp, BlueComp)
End Function
```

You will get the color on the selected cell. Just adjust to your requirements.
If you prefer to go for macros, that ones will be useful:

```
Sub GetRGBColor()

Dim HEXColor As String
Dim RGBColor As String

HEXColor = Right("000000" & Hex(ActiveCell.Interior.Color), 6)
MsgBox Hex(ActiveCell.Interior.Color)
MsgBox HEXColor

RGBColor = "RGB (" & CInt("&H" & Right(HEXColor, 2)) & _
", " & CInt("&H" & Mid(HEXColor, 3, 2)) & _
", " & CInt("&H" & Left(HEXColor, 2)) & ")"

MsgBox RGBColor, vbInformation, "Cell " & ActiveCell.Address(False, False) & ":  Fill Color"

End Sub
```

This Macro will give you the values of the color on a selected cell on RGB.

```
Sub PrintRGBColor()

Dim RedComp As Integer
Dim GreenComp As Integer
Dim BlueComp As Integer

RedComp = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Red Component Value (0-255)", Type:=2)
GreenComp = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Green Component Value (0-255)", Type:=2)
BlueComp = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Blue Component Value (0-255)", Type:=2)

ActiveCell.Interior.Color = RGB(RedComp, GreenComp, BlueComp)

End Sub
```

This one will let you to get one color by components on one selected cell.

If you need additional help, just let us know.

Hope it helps!